# [OPCUA]Unable to get reflected changes in the node-red debug window for subsequent changes in the tia portal

Tags: node-red, opc-ua, siemens

In my Node-red flow, i am taking data from Siemens PLC through OPC-UA node in node-red. I'm getting data perfectly for some-time(meaning whatever changes i make in Tia portal program is also shows in node-red debug window.[Refer to screenshot -1]).

But after certain time(2-3 minutes), whatever changes i made at Tia portal program does not reflected back in node-red debug window[Refer to screenshot -2]. I don't know why?

Also, OPCUA node status is also changing from "'Active subscribing' to 'keep-alive' to 'active subscribing'..........[Refer to screenshot -3]"

I am using

- Tia portal[Siemens V16]
- PLC sim advanced V2.0
- Node-red(windows 11)
- OPCUA contrib node(but not IIOT OPCUA node)

Those who need my-node-red flow, i have pasted it here.

```
[
    {
        "id": "b5d2b5d70adc9eec",
        "type": "tab",
        "label": "Flow 4",
        "disabled": false,
        "info": "",
        "env": []
    },
    {
        "id": "06942aed7746321a",
        "type": "function",
        "z": "b5d2b5d70adc9eec",
        "name": "NodeId Array (Static variables)",
        "func": "// Tested with Prosys static variables\nmsg.topic = \"multiple\";\nmsg.payload = [];\nmsg.payload.push({ nodeId: 'ns=3;s=\\\"SQL\".\"Excel_log_bit\"'});\nmsg.payload.push({ nodeId: 'ns=3;s=\\\"SQL\".\"H_CoExtRunTime\"'});\nmsg.payload.push({ nodeId: 'ns=3;s=\\\"SQL\".\"H_TotDefDrum\"' });\nmsg.payload.push({ nodeId: 'ns=3;s=\\\"SQL\".\"H_TotProdDrum\"'});\nmsg.payload.push({ nodeId: 'ns=3;s=\\\"SQL\".\"H_Act_Length\"'});\nmsg.payload.push({ nodeId: 'ns=3;s=\\\"SQL\".\"AvgSpeed\"' });\nmsg.payload.push({ nodeId: 'ns=3;s=\\\"SQL\".\"H_AWGrm/Mtr\"'});\nmsg.payload.push({ nodeId: 'ns=3;s=\\\"SQL\".\"H_CoExtScrapAct\"'});\nmsg.payload.push({ nodeId: 'ns=3;s=\\\"SQL\".\"H_Defects\"'});\nreturn msg;",
        "outputs": 1,
        "noerr": 0,
        "initialize": "",
        "finalize": "",
        "libs": [],
        "x": 490,
        "y": 280,
        "wires": [
            [
                "70152a7ad43e3a4c"
            ]
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": "4842bce434c17963",
        "type": "inject",
        "z": "b5d2b5d70adc9eec",
        "name": "Subscribe multiple",
        "props": [
            {
                "p": "topic",
                "vt": "str"
            }
        ],
        "repeat": "1",
        "crontab": "",
        "once": false,
        "onceDelay": 0.1,
        "topic": "multiple",
        "x": 210,
        "y": 280,
        "wires": [
            [
                "06942aed7746321a"
            ]
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": "67c900801f738564",
        "type": "function",
        "z": "b5d2b5d70adc9eec",
        "name": "Just value",
        "func": "if (msg.payload && msg.payload.value) {\n  var value = msg.payload.value.value;\n  msg.payload = value;\n  return msg;\n}\n",
        "outputs": 1,
        "noerr": 0,
        "initialize": "",
        "finalize": "",
        "libs": [],
        "x": 920,
        "y": 280,
        "wires": [
            [
                "f06aa782df1ad63e"
            ]
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": "a20ea5df904b241e",
        "type": "debug",
        "z": "b5d2b5d70adc9eec",
        "name": "",
        "active": true,
        "tosidebar": true,
        "console": false,
        "tostatus": false,
        "complete": "payload",
        "targetType": "msg",
        "statusVal": "",
        "statusType": "auto",
        "x": 1510,
        "y": 260,
        "wires": []
    },
    {
        "id": "f06aa782df1ad63e",
        "type": "join",
        "z": "b5d2b5d70adc9eec",
        "name": "",
        "mode": "custom",
        "build": "object",
        "property": "payload",
        "propertyType": "msg",
        "key": "topic",
        "joiner": "\\n",
        "joinerType": "str",
        "accumulate": false,
        "timeout": "",
        "count": "9",
        "reduceRight": false,
        "reduceExp": "",
        "reduceInit": "",
        "reduceInitType": "",
        "reduceFixup": "",
        "x": 1050,
        "y": 280,
        "wires": [
            [
                "cabe61a302bbe43b"
            ]
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": "95dd18ccee2f5d60",
        "type": "function",
        "z": "b5d2b5d70adc9eec",
        "name": "function 20",
        "func": "msg.payload = {\n    \"Excel_log_bit\": msg.payload['ns=3;s=\\\"SQL\".\"Excel_log_bit\"'] == true? 1 : 0,\n    \"H_CoExtRunTime\": msg.payload['ns=3;s=\\\"SQL\".\"H_CoExtRunTime\"'],\n    \"H_TotDefDrum\": msg.payload['ns=3;s=\\\"SQL\".\"H_TotDefDrum\"'],\n    \"H_TotProdDrum\": msg.payload['ns=3;s=\\\"SQL\".\"H_TotProdDrum\"'],\n    \"H_Act_Length\": msg.payload['ns=3;s=\\\"SQL\".\"H_Act_Length\"'],\n    \"AvgSpeed\": msg.payload['ns=3;s=\\\"SQL\".\"AvgSpeed\"'],\n    \"H_AWGrm/Mtr\": msg.payload['ns=3;s=\\\"SQL\".\"H_AWGrm/Mtr\"'],\n    \"H_CoExtScrapAct\": msg.payload['ns=3;s=\\\"SQL\".\"H_CoExtScrapAct\"'],\n    \"H_Defects\": msg.payload['ns=3;s=\\\"SQL\".\"H_Defects\"']\n}\nreturn msg;",
        "outputs": 1,
        "noerr": 0,
        "initialize": "",
        "finalize": "",
        "libs": [],
        "x": 1330,
        "y": 280,
        "wires": [
            [
                "a20ea5df904b241e"
            ]
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": "c44ead5f3ce4f08e",
        "type": "comment",
        "z": "b5d2b5d70adc9eec",
        "name": "Try-5",
        "info": "",
        "x": 170,
        "y": 240,
        "wires": []
    },
    {
        "id": "70152a7ad43e3a4c",
        "type": "OpcUa-Client",
        "z": "b5d2b5d70adc9eec",
        "endpoint": "3ec188ec73ca536f",
        "action": "subscribe",
        "deadbandtype": "a",
        "deadbandvalue": 1,
        "time": "100",
        "timeUnit": "ms",
        "certificate": "n",
        "localfile": "",
        "localkeyfile": "",
        "securitymode": "None",
        "securitypolicy": "None",
        "folderName4PKI": "",
        "maxChunkCount": "",
        "maxMessageSize": "",
        "receiveBufferSize": "",
        "sendBufferSize": "",
        "name": "",
        "x": 740,
        "y": 280,
        "wires": [
            [
                "67c900801f738564"
            ]
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": "8b05d8891b583116",
        "type": "comment",
        "z": "b5d2b5d70adc9eec",
        "name": "chat-gpt corrected program",
        "info": "what i wrote:\nmsg.payload = {\n    \"Excel_log_bit\": if(msg.payload['ns=3;s=\\\"SQL\".\"Excel_log_bit\"'] == true){\n        return 1;\n        else{\n        return 0;\n    },\n\n    \"H_CoExtRunTime\": msg.payload['ns=3;s=\\\"SQL\".\"H_CoExtRunTime\"'],\n    \"H_TotDefDrum\": msg.payload['ns=3;s=\\\"SQL\".\"H_TotDefDrum\"'],\n    \"H_TotProdDrum\": msg.payload['ns=3;s=\\\"SQL\".\"H_TotProdDrum\"'],\n    \"H_Act_Length\": msg.payload['ns=3;s=\\\"SQL\".\"H_Act_Length\"'],\n    \"AvgSpeed\": msg.payload['ns=3;s=\\\"SQL\".\"AvgSpeed\"'],\n    \"H_AWGrm/Mtr\": msg.payload['ns=3;s=\\\"SQL\".\"H_AWGrm/Mtr\"'],\n    \"H_CoExtScrapAct\": msg.payload['ns=3;s=\\\"SQL\".\"H_CoExtScrapAct\"'],\n    \"H_Defects\": msg.payload['ns=3;s=\\\"SQL\".\"H_Defects\"']\n}\nreturn msg;\n\n\ni was getting error, so i pasted the incorrect program as it is into microsoft bing chat gpt, to which it gave me :\nmsg.payload = {\n    \"Excel_log_bit\": msg.payload['ns=3;s=\\\"SQL\".\"Excel_log_bit\"'] == true? 1 : 0,\n    \"H_CoExtRunTime\": msg.payload['ns=3;s=\\\"SQL\".\"H_CoExtRunTime\"'],\n    \"H_TotDefDrum\": msg.payload['ns=3;s=\\\"SQL\".\"H_TotDefDrum\"'],\n    \"H_TotProdDrum\": msg.payload['ns=3;s=\\\"SQL\".\"H_TotProdDrum\"'],\n    \"H_Act_Length\": msg.payload['ns=3;s=\\\"SQL\".\"H_Act_Length\"'],\n    \"AvgSpeed\": msg.payload['ns=3;s=\\\"SQL\".\"AvgSpeed\"'],\n    \"H_AWGrm/Mtr\": msg.payload['ns=3;s=\\\"SQL\".\"H_AWGrm/Mtr\"'],\n    \"H_CoExtScrapAct\": msg.payload['ns=3;s=\\\"SQL\".\"H_CoExtScrapAct\"'],\n    \"H_Defects\": msg.payload['ns=3;s=\\\"SQL\".\"H_Defects\"']\n}\nreturn msg;\n\nRESULT = It worked\n\n\n\n\n\n\nThen i asked him => correct this program and use if/else statement if required:\nmsg.payload = {\n    \"Excel_log_bit\": if(msg.payload['ns=3;s=\\\"SQL\".\"Excel_log_bit\"'] == true){\n        return 1;\n        else{\n        return 0;\n    },\n\n    \"H_CoExtRunTime\": msg.payload['ns=3;s=\\\"SQL\".\"H_CoExtRunTime\"'],\n    \"H_TotDefDrum\": msg.payload['ns=3;s=\\\"SQL\".\"H_TotDefDrum\"'],\n    \"H_TotProdDrum\": msg.payload['ns=3;s=\\\"SQL\".\"H_TotProdDrum\"'],\n    \"H_Act_Length\": msg.payload['ns=3;s=\\\"SQL\".\"H_Act_Length\"'],\n    \"AvgSpeed\": msg.payload['ns=3;s=\\\"SQL\".\"AvgSpeed\"'],\n    \"H_AWGrm/Mtr\": msg.payload['ns=3;s=\\\"SQL\".\"H_AWGrm/Mtr\"'],\n    \"H_CoExtScrapAct\": msg.payload['ns=3;s=\\\"SQL\".\"H_CoExtScrapAct\"'],\n    \"H_Defects\": msg.payload['ns=3;s=\\\"SQL\".\"H_Defects\"']\n}\n\n\n\nto which it replied:\n\nvar Excel_log_bit_value;\nif (msg.payload['ns=3;s=\\\"SQL\".\"Excel_log_bit\"'] == true) {\n    Excel_log_bit_value = 1;\n} else {\n    Excel_log_bit_value = 0;\n}\n\nmsg.payload = {\n    \"Excel_log_bit\": Excel_log_bit_value,\n    \"H_CoExtRunTime\": msg.payload['ns=3;s=\\\"SQL\".\"H_CoExtRunTime\"'],\n    \"H_TotDefDrum\": msg.payload['ns=3;s=\\\"SQL\".\"H_TotDefDrum\"'],\n    \"H_TotProdDrum\": msg.payload['ns=3;s=\\\"SQL\".\"H_TotProdDrum\"'],\n    \"H_Act_Length\": msg.payload['ns=3;s=\\\"SQL\".\"H_Act_Length\"'],\n    \"AvgSpeed\": msg.payload['ns=3;s=\\\"SQL\".\"AvgSpeed\"'],\n    \"H_AWGrm/Mtr\": msg.payload['ns=3;s=\\\"SQL\".\"H_AWGrm/Mtr\"'],\n    \"H_CoExtScrapAct\": msg.payload['ns=3;s=\\\"SQL\".\"H_CoExtScrapAct\"'],\n    \"H_Defects\": msg.payload['ns=3;s=\\\"SQL\".\"H_Defects\"']\n}\n\n\nResult - It also worked",
        "x": 1310,
        "y": 240,
        "wires": []
    },
    {
        "id": "cabe61a302bbe43b",
        "type": "rbe",
        "z": "b5d2b5d70adc9eec",
        "name": "",
        "func": "rbe",
        "gap": "",
        "start": "",
        "inout": "out",
        "septopics": false,
        "property": "payload",
        "topi": "topic",
        "x": 1190,
        "y": 280,
        "wires": [
            [
                "95dd18ccee2f5d60"
            ]
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": "4d2cdd99499bac90",
        "type": "comment",
        "z": "b5d2b5d70adc9eec",
        "name": "",
        "info": "If you ever get problem with changes not being reflected in debug node for subsequent changing in tia portal, then you should refer to this link.\n\n\ntype in gooogle -> opcua node interval in node red\n\n\nor directlly - https://support.industry.siemens.com/forum/in/en/posts/using-opc-ua-sampling-intervals-with-flow-creator-node-red/263016\n",
        "x": 720,
        "y": 240,
        "wires": []
    },
    {
        "id": "3ec188ec73ca536f",
        "type": "OpcUa-Endpoint",
        "endpoint": "opc.tcp://192.168.0.1:4840",
        "secpol": "None",
        "secmode": "None",
        "none": true,
        "login": false,
        "usercert": false,
        "usercertificate": "",
        "userprivatekey": ""
    }
]
```

[image: Screenshot 1]

[image: Screenshot 2]

[image: Screenshot 3]